# What is the optimal resource to follow to learn Operating System?

Tags: operating-systems

I wanted to learn Operating System on my own. Although I have learned few basic things from here and there, but wanted to know the suggestions (books, any video lecture, etc.) from this community.

Comment: Optimal in what sense ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I mean that way which would take less time, but makes me knowledgable of almost majority of topics at an interview level.

Comment: Read Wikipedia articles :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm also learning about Operating Systems. One thing that I observed is that there is lack of quality lectures around this topic due to this topic being extremely tough. So, I tried a new experiment.

I'll now read multiple books and form an opinion. That's the most optimal way in this case.

The books that I've bought are:

- Galvin et al Operating System Concepts
- Stallings Operating Systems Internals
- Deitel et al Operating System

Other good books in this domain are:

- Operating System by william stallings (I'm not a big fan of his abstract way of presenting concepts)
- Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces

Some video lectures in this domain are:

There are udemy courses by Vignesh Sekar but they're too boring and bland and maybe basic. I'd rather read books.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jciGIvn7UfM&list=PLyqSpQzTE6M9SYI5RqwFYtFYab94gJpWk

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Q1oFPC1ElI&list=PLLDC70psjvq5hIT0kfr1sirNuees0NIbG&index=28

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z3Nw5o9dS7Q&list=PLsylUObW5M3CAGT6OdubyH6FztKfJCcFB

Course by german university.

https://www.tele-task.de/series/1231/

https://www.mi.fu-berlin.de/inf/groups/ag-tech/teaching/resources/Course-Material.html

[https://none.cs.umass.edu/~shenoy/courses/spring23/lectures/](https://none.cs.umass.edu/%7Eshenoy/courses/spring23/lectures/)

[https://www.cs.columbia.edu/~smb/classes/s06-4118/lectures.html](https://www.cs.columbia.edu/%7Esmb/classes/s06-4118/lectures.html)

[http://users.cms.caltech.edu/~donnie/cs124/lectures/](http://users.cms.caltech.edu/%7Edonnie/cs124/lectures/)

http://www.cse.iitd.ernet.in/os-lectures

https://oscourse.org/

https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/csep551/14au/video/

[https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/Classes/537/Spring2018/](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/Classes/537/Spring2018/)

http://gauss.ececs.uc.edu/Courses/c4029/

https://webcms3.cse.unsw.edu.au/COMP1521/18s2/resources/20598

https://merlot.usc.edu/cs402-m23/summer-preview.html

https://elearn.daffodilvarsity.edu.bd/course/view.php?id=7706

[https://cs.slu.edu/~dferry/courses/old/csci3500_fl20/](https://cs.slu.edu/%7Edferry/courses/old/csci3500_fl20/)

[https://ics.uci.edu/~aburtsev/238P/](https://ics.uci.edu/%7Eaburtsev/238P/)

https://warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/physics/research/condensedmatt/imr_cdt/students/david_goodwin/teaching/operating_systems/l1_concepts.pdf

https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/dahlin/Classes/UGOS/index.html

https://mycourses.aalto.fi/course/view.php?id=32526